# Why is one set of tagged not parsing?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tagging, pos-tagger

So I'm supposed to chunk some tagged sentences from the WSJ corpus using my very simple parser. When i pos tag the sentences myself it works...but using their given way to get the tagged sentences do not.

My assignment told me to use sentences 200–220 of the tagged WSJ corpus nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents(). however my parser is giving me an error.

My code which works(Manually tagging the sentences *which works*):

```
tbss = concat(treebank.sents()[200:220])
tag1 = nltk.pos_tag(tbss)
print(cp.parse(tag1))
```

Using their code which doesn't work:

```
tag2 = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents()[200:220]
print(cp.parse(tag2))
>>> ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees
```

Why exactly is the second one giving that error? I did a print of both tag 1 and tag 2 and they look almost identical...so why is one parsing and not the other...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Printing the structure might not be that helpful. Have a look at `repr(...)` of the objects, or even unpack it and inspect the substructures separately. It might also be that the exception-throwing object misses a certain method, so you need to wrap it somehow to provide the required interface.

Comment: Also, in the first case, where you apply the default POS tagger (I wouldn't call this "manually", btw), you concatenate the sentences first, so you probably get a single tagged sequence. I don't see that happening in the second case, so there you probably have multiple tagged sequences (one for every sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because you pass `cp.parse()` a list of sentences, not a list of tagged tokens. You don't show where `concat` comes from, but clearly (as @lenz commented) it concatenates the sentences into a single list of words. To do the same in the second case, you'd need `cp.parse(concat(tag2))`.

However, this is incorrect unless you have a very unusual grammar. Parsers work on one sentence at a time, so you should keep your sentences separate, not concatenate them together. Either iterate over your lists of sentences and parse each one, or parse all the tagged sentences at once with `cp.parse_sents(tag2)`. The same applies to the self-tagged treebank sentences, which should have been tagged and parsed like this:

```
tbss = treebank.sents()[200:220]
tag1 = nltk.pos_tag_sents(tbss)
parsed1 = cp.parse_sents(tag1)
for sent in parsed1:
    print(sent)
```

Comment: @alexis...thanks mate this worked...please can you take a look at my other question please which is a follow up to this question? The follow up to this question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572648/extending-the-grammar-to-handle-complex-nps    You see my main task is to chunk thse treebank sentences...but i am getting some difficulty in handling all cases...also there is little info on the web about this type of chunking syntax :(

Comment: I won't do that, sorry. Your other question is not about the nltk's syntax but about English grammar.